# Sending String Paramater in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, countdowntimer

i am developing a countdown timer with JS, then i want to send data if the time is up with AJAX. now i have a problem to send it, could you guys help me to solve this? below is my code:

```js
    if (distance > 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";

      var status = "EXPIRED";
      var r = '';

      $.ajax({
          async : false,
          url: '#',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          method: 'POST',
          cache: false,
          data: {'status': status},
          success: function (result) {
            r = result;
            console.log(r);
          }
      });
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Could you share more details of the issue, what is the problem you are facing exactly? If you are getting any errors, please share those too.

Comment: cant display output when using console.log(r)

Comment: you get an error because of invalid url hence your console never fires

Comment: I guess the problem is with the request you are making. Please add the following before closing the ajax: `error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { console.log(xhr.responseText);}` and share that error message, so we can help you better.

Comment: yes, it works. it must be valid url, i thought if its just for testing nvm to delete it. thanks @EugeneSunic

Comment: @YunanHelmiAlAnbarry no problem